# Passing a void function as a parameter to a void function

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, void

This might seem stupid but please...

```
class Button{

public:

    void func();

    void Button(void func()){

        //Do something.

        //Like if(something){
    func();
}

    }

};
```

How do I pass `func()` as a parameter to `Button()`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to declare the parameter of the function Button as a pointer to a member function because func is a member function.

Comment: Take a look at the meaning of function pointers or alternatively std::function

Answer (score 1):

`func` cannot be passed into `Button` as an argument. The parameter of `Button` is a pointer to function, and pointers to functions cannot point to non-static member functions. `func` is a non-static member function and it cannot be pointed by a pointer to function.

Solutions:

- Accept a pointer to member function as the parameter instead of a pointer to function.
- Make `func` a non-member function or a static member function which can be pointed by a pointer to function.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot but I still get this error: `error: return type specification for constructor invalid|`. Does this have to do with something else?

Comment: @EEE It's another problem. Your function declaration is a mix of constructor and a regular function syntax. Either remove `void` or change the name of the function to something other than the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 and later, you can use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), eg:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class Button{
public:
    void Button(std::function<void()> func){
        if (something){
            func();
        }
    }
};
```

This way, you can equally accept any callable type, whether that be a standalone function, a lambda, the result of `std::bind()`, etc.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot but I still get this error: `error: return type specification for constructor invalid|`. Does this have to do with something else?

Comment: @EEE That has to do with `Button()` being the same name as the `Button` class, so it gets treated as a class constructor, which can't have a return value specified.  Drop the `void` if you really intend for `Button()` to be a constructor. Otherwise, rename `Button()` to something else.